# Axiom of Limitation of Size Reference Request

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

On the wiki page for the axiom of limitation of size in NGB is states that the axiom of replacement and the axiom of global choice are equivalent to the axiom of limitation of size (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size)

I tried my best to check through the references given on the wiki page (I couldn't get a hold of all of them and some of them are written in German/French which is a slight impasse for me)

I was wondering if anybody knew of a reference for this claim?

I did find a proof in some lecture notes by Forster here (https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tf/axiomsofsettheory.pdf) but that uses Corets axiom which is referenced in one of Forster's papers that I can't get a hold of (and I have no idea what Coret's axiom is)

Comment: As of this moment, your question is the first google hit for "Coret's axiom".

Comment: @Hurkyl: Google filters and reorganizes results according to the user. They know you might be interested in results from MSE, so they put these on top of *your* search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a reference, but here's the proof.

Assume Replacement and Global Choice. If $X$ is mappable onto $V$, then $X$ cannot form a set (by Replacement). Conversely, suppose $X$ doesn't form a set. Using Global Choice we can map $X$ 1-1 onto an initial segment of the ordinals, call them $Y$. Since $Y$ can't form a set (by Replacement), $Y = On$. By Global Choice, $X$ is thus 1-1 with $V$.

Assume LoS. Clearly, Replacement follows. Now, $On$ cannot form a set, so it is mappable onto $V$ (by LoS). So $V$ is well-orderable.

Comment: I wonder if by requiring that the map is onto $\rm Ord$ rather than $V$, we can still prove the axioms of replacement (and union), but get wiggle room for failure of global choice, or even choice itself.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the proof of union does go via global choice -- so that may not follow. But certainly Replacement will. My guess is the same as yours re. choice and global choice -- i.e. that they won't follow. But I'm not competent enough to construct a counter-model.

Comment: Well, here's a point to consider. If $X$ is a proper class, then the map $x\mapsto\operatorname{rank}(x)$ has an unbounded range in $\rm Ord$, so it can be collapsed to a surjection. Now just taking any model where the axiom of choice fails should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to track down a reference to von Neumann's collected works, I imagine it would be far to convenient if there happened to be a translation somewhere

Comment: No worries! Do let me know if my proof could be clearer in any way.