# Bibliography about the Axiom of Limitation of Size

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I'm trying to study Von Neumann's Axiom of Limitation of Size, but I'm unable to find good bibliography about it. In fact, the only place I've found in which it is stated formally is Wikipedia. Does anyone know of good bibliography? I'm aware that there is already a similar question in Mathstackexchange, but couldn't found any references there either:
[Axiom of Limitation of Size Reference Request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843454/axiom-of-limitation-of-size-reference-request)

Comment: Maybe useful: Michael Hallett, [Cantorian Set Theory and Limitation of Size (1984)](https://books.google.it/books?id=TM3AKPYdQVgC&pg=PA270), page 270-on.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is useful, I've found the original source of the axiom: Von Neuman's 'An Axiomatization of Set Theory' (1925), that can be found on 'From Frege to Gödel' (page 400, axiom IV.2). In fact, in page 397 it is said "(the function) must be single valued, but it need not be one-to-one". Many textbooks (and the Stanford Encyclopedia) introduce the axiom as a bijection between a proper class and $V$, but that's not actually correct: it just needs to be surjective.